# Linking of rule '//tensorflow/python:_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' failed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install Tensorflow on my laptop which has i5 and 8GB RAM.

When I am building the Tensorflow from source 
I use

```
bazel build --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" --copt=-march=native //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Everything seems to go well but at the end I get this error

```
`ERROR: /home/siladittya/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:3166:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow/python:_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' failed (Exit 1)

/usr/bin/ld.gold: fatal error: bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/quantize_and_dequantize_op/tensorflow/core/kernels/quantize_and_dequantize_op.pic.o: read: Input/output error

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
```

`

I looked up a few posts in some forums, but they are saying that it can be solved using `--local_resources` but when I used that argument,

```
`bazel build --local_resources 8000,2.0,2.0 --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`
```

I am getting the same error again.

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Either your disk is full or partition is otherwise corrupted.

Comment: yes, I did `fsck` from the recovery mode. and then it was OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `fsck` on `/dev/sda1` i.e. on the system root partition solved the problem.

And it seems, that it is not a problem that can be solved using `--local_resources`